# Angular 14 multiple link icon request when appending fragment html to document.head

Tags: javascript, typescript, request, href, angular14

- Angular 14.0.1
- Nx 14.7

The case is:
I want to build link href dynamically when app starts, as it depends on the dynamic config.
Whenever I append or modify link href in the head, request for the used one icon made (all request the same). I this case 7 request made each time I reload the page. I've tried to add this script via  tag to html - only one request is made. Seems like the cause is angular. Any ideas?

app.coomponent.ts

```
appendLinks(): void {
    const links = [
      {
        rel: "icon",
        sizes: "192x192",
        href: "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196",
      },
      {
        rel: "apple-touch-icon-precomposed",
        sizes: "180x180",
        href: "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196",
      },
      {
        rel: "apple-touch-icon-precomposed",
        sizes: "180x180",
        href: "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196",
      },
      {
        rel: "apple-touch-icon-precomposed",
        sizes: "180x180",
        href: "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196",
      },
      {
        rel: "apple-touch-icon-precomposed",
        sizes: "180x180",
        href: "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196",
      },
      {
        rel: "apple-touch-icon-precomposed",
        sizes: "180x180",
        href: "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196",
      },
      {
        rel: "icon",
        type: "image/x-icon",
        href: "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196",
      }];
    const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    links.forEach(l => {
      const link: HTMLLinkElement = document.createElement('link');
      link.setAttribute('rel', l.rel);
      link.setAttribute('href', l.href);
      if (l.sizes) {
        link.setAttribute('sizes', l.sizes)
      }
      if (l.type) {
        link.setAttribute('type', l.type)
      }
      frag.appendChild(link);
    });
    document.head.appendChild(frag);
  }
```

I've tried to add links within angular and without. Without angular request made only once and all icon links are appended - this is what I want to achieve within angular. I've tried to run it outside NgZone. Didn't work.